# How to use bearer token for get data

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem getting data with the bearer token. The token is correct, but if I put bearer, it always says "message": "Unauthenticated." "status_code": 401

```
Route::get('/getdata', function () {

    $token = 'mybrearere=xxxxxx<example';

    $getdata = Http::get('http://example/api/posts', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ]
    ]);

    return $getdata;
});
```

I tried in Postman with a bearer token from a login is okay but I use Laravel always 401.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, when you are making a GET request using the Http facade, you should pass the headers as the second argument to the `get` method. However, you pass the headers as a nested array inside the second argument.

```php
Route::get('/getdata', function () {

    $token = 'mybrearere=xxxxxx<example';

    $getdata = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ])->get('http://example/api/posts');

    return $getdata;
});
```